# Why do I need to pass the model class instead of id in Entity Framework Core relationship

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core, relationship

Let's say that I have a model class in .NET called "B" which has a required fk (one-to-one relationship) from the model class "A".

The code of the models should be something like:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual required B ClassB { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int A_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual required A ClassB { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's say that I have a record with the id "1" in the table "A" and I want to add a record in the class "B" with an fk of this record 1.

In my mind, this code should be enough:

```
var classBToAdd = new B
{
   A_ID = 1
}

_myRepo.Add(classBToAdd);
```

But I can't to this because the relationship is required:

```
public virtual required A ClassB { get; set; }
```

And if it isn't required, I receive the following warning:

> Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable.

Why do I need to specify the full object? In some scenarios, this could mean that I'll need to do a big query just to have the full object to save.

Comment: You are thinking in database terms instead of ORM terms.  Remove the Id properties (EF will automatically add them), and use the object properties instead of the Id properties.

Comment: Entity creates a hierarchy model that maps the c# classes/properties to the database tables/columns.  The entity interface uses the model and must send the model not the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio is on the right track, but there is a simpler answer. EF Convention for identifying FKs is based on the type, not property name. This means that if you want to declare a FK that doesn't follow the implied convention you need to tell EF what to use:

```
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
 
    public int A_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(A_ID))]
    public virtual A ClassA { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need the required as both A and A_ID are non-null-able. Now if you want to create a B in isolation and simply associate it with an A record without using the ClassA navigation property it should work as you expect.

If you are creating an A and a B together, in the very simplest form:

```
var newA = new A() { /* populate A details */ }; 
newA.Bs.Add(new B() { /* populate B details */ });
_context.As.Add(newA);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Provided the relationships are mapped correctly, EF works out the insert order and FK associations automatically, which is the point of using an ORM vs. ADO-style CRUD operations.

I would advise against using what appears to be a repository pattern over-top the EF DbContext. The DbContext already serves as a unit of work container and the DbSets serve as Repositories so attempting to abstract these is both unnecessary and will be prone to introducing problems and limitations for capabilities that EF can provide and performance. There are arguably valid reasons to introduce UoW and Repository patterns over EF for things like facilitating unit testing or implementing core filtering/authorization checks, but when starting out I recommend using the DbContext and DbSets directly to avoid introducing complications.

Edit: Non-Nullable reference types errors and EF. The compiler will complain with a warning, or an exception if your project has opted for strict enforcement, if you have a required ClassA that isn't populated.

The most correct way to address this would be:

```
[Required]
public virtual A? ClassA { get; set; }
```

Other options include:

```
public virtual A ClassA { get; set; } = null!;
```

or using a forgiveness marker for a constructor:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    public B()
    { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
```

- Note this constructor is for class B and disables the warning/exceptions for this class so in our case, about the non-null ClassA reference. I typically have public constructor for initializing entities with all required fields so you can mark this default constructor as `protected`, otherwise if you just use a default constructor on entities (or have no constructor) make this `public`.

Comment: I think that the best way to choose keys, foreign keys, relationships, required properties, rowversion, etc.. is overriding **OnModelCreating**. Furthermore, there might be an even simpler way to create the two entities: 

**B classBToAdd = new B
{
    ClassA = new A()
};

db.Add(classBToAdd);
db.SaveChanges();**

Comment: But if do this "public virtual A ClassA { get; set; }", i still receive the error "Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable.".

Comment: Yeah, EF's conventions are a double-edged sword. They can save a bit of time but can cost time when you need something that doesn't quite fit and will be left guessing at why it doesn't work unless you recognize where you've deviated from their convention. Attributes can do 95% of the heavy lifting but there are still a few scenarios around relationships like some many-to-many scenarios that you pretty much need explicit config. I like to use IEntityTypeConfiguration as part of OnModelCreating to nicely compartmentalize the configuration.

Comment: Ah, Nullable references. Are you getting a warning or an exception? If an exception then your project has opted to escalate CS8618 to an exception. This can be a nuisance with EF entities where EF manages references that will be required but C# null-able references will complain. You can either make it nullable with a `[Required]` attribute, or tell the nullable reference check to be quiet with a `= null!;` or a marked constructor.. I will update the answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

The line **public int A_ID { get; set; }** in your code, doesn't automatically identify a foreign key. The right code is:

```
public int AId { get; set; }
```

How do you create a class A object first (to obtain its reference Id), if it requires an object of type B not existing yet?

This code works:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual B ClassB { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A ClassA { get; set; }
}
```

...and in your Main():

```
A newClassA = new A();                                    
db.Add(newClassA);
db.SaveChanges();
            
B classBToAdd = new B
{
    AId = newClassA.Id
};

db.Add(classBToAdd);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Do not do this.... `SaveChanges` should only be called a single time as the DbContext represents a unit of work. If creating an A and related B at the same time, create the A, create a B associating it to the A via the navigation property and call `SaveChanges()`.  EF manages the insert order and FK associations automatically.